# Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object '_worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

Here are my code to export all sheets of excel to PDF:

```
Sub printing()

Dim i As Integer, wkb As String, head As String, nm As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'get folder path
wkb = InputBox("Enter folder path:", , ActiveWorkbook.Path)
If Right(wkb, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then wkb = wkb & Application.PathSeparator

'head of file name
head = InputBox("Enter head of file name", , "Test")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    If ws.Visible = True Then
        ws.Select
        nm = ws.Range("A1")
        If nm <> "" Then
            'save
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=wkb & head & nm & ".pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

I run this macro on my Mac and my friend's Mac, But my Mac is pass,and my friend's mac not pass and occured an errors:

> Run time error '1004':
>
> Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object '_worksheet' failed

Can you tell me a solution to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked all the references are the same on the two machines?

Comment: This method was added from Excel 2007 - is your friend using an earlier version of Excel on his Mac than you are?

Comment: @MacroMan: Two machines same OS version,same Office version