Getting error while saving PDF: Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object '_worksheet' failed
Tryint to run this VBA macro and getting error:
    Sub SaveAsPDF()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim filePath As String
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim printArea As String
        Dim pdfPath As String
    
        ' Set the worksheet you are working with
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice format") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    
        ' Define the file path and name for the PDF
        filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        fileName = Range("V13").Value + ".pdf" ' Change this to your desired file name
        pdfPath = filePath & "\" & fileName
    
        ' Define the print area
        printArea = "A1:T51" ' Change this to your desired print area
        ws.PageSetup.printArea = printArea
    
        ' Export the sheet as a PDF
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=pdfPath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
        ' Optional: Display a confirmation message
        MsgBox "PDF saved as: " & fileName & vbCrLf & _
               "Print Area: " & printArea & vbCrLf & _
               "File Path: " & pdfPath
    End Sub

Gettingg the below error while running the VBA:
Run time error '1004':
Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object '_worksheet' failed
Can you tell me a solution to fix it?
Thanks.

Cannot reproduce.  Works for me.

Is pdfPath a valid path?

Oddly enough unanswered question from eight years ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389659/method-exportasfixedformat-of-object-worksheet-failed

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/error-exporting-excel-workbooks-to-pdf.1001563/ - file permission issues? Can you change the file path to test?

Should Range("V13") be changed to ws.Range("V13")?

Note that when a file was never saved e.g. Book1, its path is "". Please share what's in V13 since there are forbidden characters when naming a file.

Taking into account the suggestions above I am going to guess it has something to do with file permissions.  When trying to save this file directly to a root directory of my computer I get the same error.  I suggest you investigate the following (as per suggestions above):

Make sure that a directory is specified if the file is not previously saved, so instead of assuming that filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path is valid, add error checking.
Make sure you are reading the file name from the correct cell - ws.Range("V13")
Make sure you have write permission to the folder you are trying to save your new document - add code to check for it if required

